# Fubini for Radon measures

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for a reference where the Fubini theorem for Radon measures is proved but so far I have not found anything.

What I have seen so far is that if we have a Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$ and $\nu$ on $Y$ then we are able to build a radon measure on $X \times Y$ using the Riez representation theorem and the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact and Hausdorff.

However when it comes to the Fubini theorem I have only seen it proved for the case where $X$ and $Y$ are $\sigma$-finite, and I would wish to prove it in a case where $X$ and $Y$ are not $\sigma$-finite. Is this possible? I have seen a book state that this fact is true.

Comment: THe carrier of the function $f$ that you want to integrate $\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:f(x,y)\neq0\}$ should $\sigma$-finite with respect to the product of the radon measures on $X$ and $Y$. Many books deal with this, for example Cohn's measure theory, Bichteler's Integration: A functional approach.

Comment: Thank you for the references I, I really liked Cohn's approach, however he says that the carrier should be contained in a rectangle whose sides are $\sigma$-finite. This seams close to saying that the carrier is $\sigma$-finite, however is it equivalent? It seems a bit stronger, because it seams that we can take any space $X$ non $\sigma$-finite and then any space $Y$ with measure $0$ and $X \times Y$ would be $\sigma$-finite but not contained in a rectangle whose sides are $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Perhaps answering this question will lear things for you: If a set $A\subset X\times Y$ has finite $\mu\otimes\nu$-measure, can it be covered by a countable collection of boxes $C\times D$ with $\mu(C)<\infty $ and $\nu(D)<\infty$?

Comment: Ok thanks to your comment I think I understand. I would say that since $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact and Hausdorff then yes, for every set $A$ such that $\mu \otimes \nu (A) < + \infty$ then it can be written as an "almost" disjoint countable union of sets $E_n \times F_n$ such that $\mu(E_n) < + \infty$ and $\nu(E_n) < + \infty$. I would say that to prove this we use the fact that $X \times Y$ is locally compact to find in each point $z \in X \times Y$ a compact set $K$ such that $x \in K$ and since $\mu \otimes \nu$ is a Radon measure we must have $\mu \otimes \nu (K) < + \infty$.

Comment: Then to prove the Fubini theorem if the carrier $C$ of the function is $\sigma$-finite but using the previous argument we can write $C$ as almost disjoint countable union of sets $E_n \times F_n$ which both have a finite measure. Thus we have $\int_{X \times Y} f d \mu \otimes \nu = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{E_n \times F_n} f d \mu \otimes \nu$ and to conclude we notice that since $E_n$ and $F_n$ have finite measure they are $\sigma$-finite which means that we can apply the usual Fubini theorem for $\sigma$-finite spaces on $E_n \times F_n$ and this gives us the result. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct, the carrier is $\sigma$-finite if it is contained in a countable union of boxes of finite $\mu\otimes \nu$-measure.